# DLL error on PyQT5 .exe project deployed by Pyinstaller and cx-freeze

Tags: python, dll, pyqt5, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I am trying to deploy my PyQT5 project to other users but having trouble to get a working version. First attempt I freeze my project with cx-freeze. `(Python 3.8, PyQT5 5.14.2, cx-freeze 6.1)` Worked on my computer but when I try to run .exe on Windows 7 Service Pack 1 OS, I got `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing` error even latest Visual C++ redistribution update installed. Then I refreeze my project with PyInstaller --onefile command `(Python 3.8, PyQT5 5.14.2, PyInstaller 3.6)` and got same error but this time additionly I saw this:

[image]

The thing that makes me confuse is file path on command prompt is actually my computer's path. (C:\users\Asus is my username not installed user's) I couldnt find any solution on previous answers. All helps are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I cannot actually help you with this issue, but, in my experience, I know from experience that cx_Freeze displays the path of the original project structure (I don't know about PyInstaller, though, but since they're conceptually similar, I'm guessing it's possible that it's a common collateral issue).

Comment: Probably PyInstaller does same. How did you overcome on this issue?

Comment: I didn't consider it a "real" issue, but I decided to move the project to a more "anonymous" root directory.

Comment: ahh i see. It wont work for me :(

Comment: You can use the [Dependencies program](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to investigate further. It's a rewrite of the old [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/), which is no longer maintained (but you can still use [its documentation](https://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/contents.htm) to understand the concepts of the Dependencies tool).

Comment: Thank you for advice i will check it for sure but I think real issue is those tools are not packaging completely. They still need some dependencies from outside folder